# is Google Analytics RollBack possible?

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-api

I've updated refund information with transaction ids which i get from our e-commerce site API. it seems our api sent transaction ids that was not sent to Google Analytics 360 in the first place. So I see refunds in Google Analytics 360 that is not added as Sale before.

I have API Call response ids logged.

Can I make a call to Google Analytics to rollback that actions for that ids ? 
Any idea ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Google analytics data is write only.  Once the hits have been sent they are set in stone there is no way to rollback anything you sent to Google analytics.

If this is an ecommers transaction then what is normally done is that you send another hit negating the original hit.   So if you sent 1 and you want to remove it you send a -1 and it works out in the end. see [reverse eCommerce transaction](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1037443?hl=en)

Comment: thanks for reply,
I've transaction ids of api calls, could i send "cancel this processes" etc ?

Comment: If you sent data to Google analytics its there you cant unsend it.  Not exactly sure what your doing as the Google analytics api is for requesting data from google analytics not sending it to.  Are you using the measurement protocol or something?

Comment: thank you again,I take the transection ids of refunds from my e-commerce site,then send it to Google Analytics in CSV then log the response id,